# Drawing table/board in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to create a game whose name is "Same" in Racket 5.0.2 version.

Here is explanation of the game:
http://download.racket-lang.org/docs/5.0.2/html/games/same.html?q=games

I created a row and draw it:

```
a: width
b: height
r: radius

    (define (color x)  ///for random colors
      (cond [(< (random x) 100) 'blue]
            [(< (random x) 200) 'purple]
            [(< (random x) 300) 'yellow]
            [(< (random x) 400) 'red]
            [else 'green]))

    (define-struct top (coord color))
    (define (row x y)
      (if (> x (- a r)) empty
          (cons (make-top (make-posn x y)(color 500)) (row (+ x (* 2 r)) y))))

    (define (draw-row L)
      (if (empty? L) #f
          (and
            (draw-solid-disk (top-coord (first L)) r (top-color (first L)))
            (draw-row (rest L)))))
```

So I've got a top row included 20 disks with random colors. But I need 200 disks in 20 rows and 10 columns. So I created a board like this:

```
    (define (board x y)
      (if (> y (- b r)) empty
          (cons (row x y) (board x (+ y (* 2 r))))))
```

But I couldn't draw it. I tried to create a function as "draw-row" but I got error.

**So my question is: How can I draw this board?**

Comment: Which error did you get? Which libraries are you requiring?

Comment: I tried lots of things and got a bunch of errors...You can see one of them below.
Anyway, I called "draw-row" function 10 times for each row and I've 200 disks now like I want. However, I don't think so that this is the best way for doing this.
By the way, I'm using "draw.rkt" teachpack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw a row, and a board is just a list of rows, so I would expect

```
(define (draw-board b) 
    (for-each draw-row b))
```

to Just Work.

Based on your comment, an example I would expect to work:

```
(draw-board (board 10 10))
```

and it does for me, at least.

Comment: "b" is list of rows in here, right? so i called this function:
    (draw-board (row 20 20))
but i got error again.
---> first: expects a non-empty list; given: (make-top (make-posn 20 20) 'red)

Comment: `draw-row` uses `empty`, `first` and `rest`, so it expects a list. However, `make-top` returns a new struct, not a list. It looks like `draw-row` is being passed a `top` rather than a listOf `top`.

Comment: thanks for this great solution.
and one more thing, I'm new here, if I have more problems about this project, should I ask in this topic or create a new question?

Comment: @lombranzo I'm glad it's working out. Please create new questions if you have any further ones, it makes it much easier for other people to find the answers later.